# ReactJS Components Not loading unless you reload the site for the 2nd time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, chart.js

```
    var img;

    var dateFormat = require('dateformat');
    var count;
    let arrayIMG = []
    var storage = firebase.storage();
    var storeRef = storage.ref('images/')
    const config =  {

       ...
    };

    if (!firebase.apps.length) {
        firebase.initializeApp(config);
    }


    const subContStyle = {
        width: '450px',
        height: '60px',
        marginLeft: '90px'

    };

    const photoStyle = {
        width: '400px',
        height: '200px'
    };

    const MainFeedStyle = {
        marginLeft: '40px',
        width: '1050px',
        height: '500px',
        overflowY: 'auto'

    }

    const footer = {
        marginTop: '80px'
    };

    const h2Style = {
        marginTop: '60px',
        marginLeft: '100px',
        fontstyle: 'Century Gothic'
    };

    const button_style = {
        marginLeft: "6px"
    };

    const uploadBtn = {
        marginRight: "5px"
    };
    const styles = {
        card: {
            maxWidth: 345,
        },
        media: {
            height: 140,
        },
    };


    const headStyle = {
        height: '530px',
        overflowY: 'auto',
        width: '1140px',
        marginTop: '-130px',


    };

    const perDivStyle = {
        width: '60%',
        height: '20%',
        marginLeft: '200px'
    }




    class Feed extends Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            // this.state = {}

            this.state = {
                arrayIMGS: arrayIMG,
                news: [],
                title: [],
                dateCreated: []

            };
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            var that = this

            firebase.database().ref('/IMAHE').on("child_added", function (arrayIMG) {
                let newData = [...that.state.arrayIMGS]

                var yeah = dateFormat(arrayIMG.val().createdAt,"dddd, mmmm dS, yyyy, h:MM:ss TT")
                newData.push(arrayIMG.val().url)
                that.setState({ arrayIMGS: newData})
            })
        }

        render() {
            return(

                <div>
                    <div style={headStyle}>
                        <div style={perDivStyle}>




             {this.state.arrayIMGS.map((e) =>

                         { return (
                            <ListGroup>
                                <ListGroupItem >
                                    <Card>
                                        {/*{alert("URL: "+e)}*/}
                                        {/*{alert("Indexes: "+index)}*/}
                                        <CardImg top width="50%" src={e} alt="Card image cap" />
                                        <CardBody>
                                            <CardTitle>{e.title}</CardTitle>
                                            <CardText>This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</CardText>
                                            <CardText>
                                                <small className="text-muted">{this.state.dateCreated}</small>
                                            </CardText>
                                        </CardBody>
                                    </Card>
                                </ListGroupItem>
                            </ListGroup>
                        )}
                        )}

                    </div>

                    <div style={footer}>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
    export default Feed;
```

components (chartJS and mapping images from firebase) not working well in first load unless you reload the page. The function of this module is to show user all the images that are being uploaded by other users, so it is expected to load all the images once the page is loaded, but in my case it's not working that way, I have to reload the page to make it work

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: sorry about that... I'm having hard time copy pasting my code @SivadassN

Comment: You should add all the code to understand what's the behaviour of your component.

Comment: It looks like your `setState` doesn't wait for your async firestore data so it probably renders the component before it gets the data.

Try to check adding console log to it: `that.setState({ arrayIMGS: newData}, () => console.log(this.state));`

Comment: @Vrle it return an error. TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of null

Comment: That's probably because of that strange `var that = this`.
Why don't you just use `this.setState()` and `[...this.state.arrayIMGS]` ?

You can take a look at the google's ajax calls from componentDidMount example here: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html

Comment: hmm... I did make your suggestion friend, but it will return TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of null

Answer (score 0):

I think making same call in componentDidUpdate should work but be aware it will trigger stackoverflow so you should add condition to stop setState.

Comment: and also when I navigate to other page it will only return 1 image

Comment: Can you give more details about navigate to other page.